# How to hide a bar chart with an empty list of objects

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a bar chart in my report. In some cases the list of objects which is sent from the Java application is empty. In that cases I want to hide the bar chart in the report, but I cannot do it. It would be great if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a "print when expression" on the chart and/or on the band containing it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{male}==10]]></printWhenExpression>`

You can specify the condition here:  `<![CDATA[$F{male}==10]]>`

**Complete solution**

```
 <barChart>
   <chart isShowLegend="false" evaluationTime="Report">
     <reportElement x="0" y="5" width="201" height="131" >
       <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
       <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{male}==10]]></printWhenExpression>
     </reportElement>
     <chartTitle>
       <titleExpression><![CDATA["Population"]]></titleExpression>
     </chartTitle>
     <chartSubtitle/>
     <chartLegend/>
   </chart>
   ....
```